# paypal add to cart how to override redirection?

Tags: paypal

Background: I just created a button from paypal and when I click it it automatically takes me to the shopping cart. I was able to edit it so that when I click continue shopping to redirects me to the followup page I created for it.

Question: Is it possible to instead make it so when people click add to cart it immediately takes them to my followup page WITHOUT taking them to the cart?

Alternate: If the above is NOT possible is it instead possible to make it so the user CANNOT checkout on the first page so they are forced to click continue shopping?

Thanks.

Comment: _When_ you send your payment request to Paypal is up to you. You can control all of that - re: keep user at your site _until it's time to pay_ (common "add to cart"/"checkout flows). "How" is going to be too broad for SO because there are so many ways of doing it based entirely on what you want to achieve, your platform and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can be more specific, and I'm not sure how this could be considered "too broad" it's a specific question about using the the paypal shopping cart - add to cart button. Which by default, brings you to the shopping cart when you click it, and I just want to make it got to a page of My choosing instead of the shopping cart. Preferably using only their code(plus the power user lines of thier code, that I can add to it), no plugins, not custom carts, etc...

Comment: At the very least a place to start would be helpful. As I mentioned I did find that I could over ride the continue shopping button using their code (found in their documentation)to take them to the desired page. Unfortunately I have not found a way to disable checkout on that page.